# How to get transactions to a @PostConstruct CDI bean method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions, cdi

I'm experimenting with Java EE 7, CDI, JPA and JSF.

When the webapp starts, I would like to run an initialization method in my CDI bean (marked with @PostConstruct) that does some work with the database (inserts some rows etc..). For this I need a transaction, but this wasn't as easy as I expected.

I have tried adding @Transactional annotation to my method, but apparently it only works with EJB. I actually tried converting my bean to EJB instead of CDI bean, but I still didn't get transaction to my @PostConstruct method. It worked with other methods in the bean, but not with my @PostConstruct initialization method.

Then I read about creating method interceptor to get transactions to CDI beans:

http://eubauer.de/kingsware/2012/01/16/cdi-and-transactions-e-g-in-jboss-7-0-2/

I tried this too, but no luck. It doesnt work either.

So how does one get transactions to a @PostConstruct initialization method in a CDI bean?

Comment: Why do you say that it only works with EJB?  Java EE 7 added `@Transactional` support for CDI as well, moving transactions to its own spec.

Comment: You're right about regular methods, but it doesn't seem to be working with `@PostConstruct` initializer method for some reason. It would seem like a natural place to do some database related initialization work requiring a transaction. Maybe there is some other way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: This sounds like a bug then in your app server.  What app server are you using?

Comment: Forgot to mention that, its GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)

Comment: confirm that trying to call an EJB to persist or do any operation on the database from a postConstruct() method inside CDI bean doesn't work. I am also using GlassFish Server 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it seems that:

> In the @PostConstruct (as with the afterPropertiesSet from the InitializingBean interface)
>   there is no way to ensure that all the post processing is already done, so (indeed) there
>   can be no Transactions. The only way to ensure that that is working is by using a 
>   TransactionTemplate.

So the only way to do something with the database from the @PostConstruct is to do something like this:

```
@Service("something")
public class Something 
{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("transactionManager")
    protected PlatformTransactionManager txManager;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        TransactionTemplate tmpl = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
        tmpl.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                //PUT YOUR CALL TO SERVICE HERE
            }
        });
   }
}
```

NOTE: similar thread but referencing Spring framework [@Transactional on @PostConstruct method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method)

Comment: In a managed bean with application scope with `@ManagedBean(eager = true)` queries and persisting seems to work with EclipseLink 2.4.2, but not Hibernate 5.2.10.Final (causes `LazyInitializationException`).